# How to enable/disable Macros in TeXstudio with a short-cut?

Tags: macros, texstudio

I am using TeXstudio 3.0.1. I see it is very useful to use macros for *fast typing*. For example, I use “tra” to replace “treatment alternative” because that phase appears many times.
However, I have **encountered an issue** as in the following example. When I try to type the word “illustrative”, I type “illustra”, and as usual, TeXstudio immediately (after letter a) replaces by “illustreatment alternative”. This is unexpected “**side effect**”.

**Now talking about solutions**. I thought one way is to change “tra” into another “Trigger” (term in TeXstudio). Obviously, this is not efficient as whatever I change I may encounter the same issue. Another solution is to enable/disable macros when necessary with a short-cut. For example, when I disable, I can type “illustrate” as usual. After that, I can enable again.

Do you know whether it is possible and how?

Do you know any other efficient solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Obviously, this is not efficient as whatever I change I may encounter the same issue.

You can assign any regexp — unlikely in a normal text — that suits you. For example, `tra\t` means typing "tra" and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Or `tra\s\s` which means typing "tra" and pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> twice.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is what I am looking for. To your experience, which one is better, space or tab. I feel more comfortable with spaces.

Comment: Personally, I'm just used to Tab because it's often used for autocompletion and usually doesn't appear after words. I'd like to emphasize once again: you can use `\t`, `\s`, `--`, `_` or any other symbol combination you find convenient.